# Pull Role information from Authorization header in Hasura

Tags: reactjs, authentication, jwt, auth0, hasura

I'm currently using Auth0 with Hasura for a React project, and I've run into some confusion when it comes to authentication.

Hasura documentation states you can pass `x-hasura-role` to your request to specify the users role. This is great for testing as I can easily jump between roles, and is easy to do with the Hasura console.

However, I don't want this option to be available for production, then any user could just specify `x-hasura-role=admin` in the request header and they'd have full admin access. I assumed these flags would be disabled in production, and that those roles would be pulled form the signed JWT key with the Hasura claims.

What I'd like to do is for Hasura to pull "role" (`x-hasura-role`) from my `Authorization` JWT token, which looks like this when decoded:

```
{
  "https://hasura.io/jwt/claims": {
    "x-hasura-role": "admin",
    "x-hasura-default-role": "user",
    "x-hasura-allowed-roles": [
      "admin",
      "user"
    ],
    "x-hasura-user-id": "auth0|42a80d679dc71e396ce57cd1"
  },
  ...
}
```

So really I have 2 questions:

1. Does Hasura allow variables like `x-haura-role` in production? If so, what's the appropriate way to handle this?
2. Do I need to pull the `x-hasura-role` out of my JWT key myself and pass it via my Apollo Client? Again, I don't see how this would work in production, as anyone could just set `x-hasura-role`, why can't Hasura just pull it from it's "Hasura Claims" that I added?
   [image]

I feel like I'm missing a piece of information somewhere here, thank you!

Comment: The whole point of using JWTs is that people can't just change it since it then becomes invalid when validated. It's not completely clear what your concern is.

Comment: @super Right, so what you're saying is without a valid JWT in the Auth header `x-hasura-role` wouldn't be accepted anyways. But why can't Hasura just pull tthe role from my claims?

Comment: What do you mean, pull it? Do you want Hasura to modify your JWT? If you don't want a JWT with `x-hasura-role` in it's payload, then don't generate a JWT with `x-hasura-role` in the payload.

Comment: Or at least generate one with the right role.

Comment: No I want Hasura to determine my role based on my JWT key... Sending it as a separate header field doesn't seem secure outside of dev. This question is Hasura specific.

Comment: I would assume that's how it works. Since anything else would be completely ludicrous. That is generally the whole point of using JWTs. So the question then becomes, why do you think that's not how it works? And have you actually verified that in production as well?

Comment: Yeah, that's how I assumed it worked. But it doesn't work, I set the auth header to the above, and included no other `x-hasura-*` headers, and I'm rejected based off of my role.

Comment: So, clearly there is something wrong with your configuration then. Did you read the docs? What have you tried?

Comment: Yes, I wasn't sure if I was misreading, because as far as I'm aware this should be working out if the box once you set an admin secret. https://hasura.io/learn/graphql/hasura/authentication/5-test-with-headers/

Answer (score 1):

So it seems instead of using `x-hasura-role`, if I set `x-hasura-default-role` to my desired role, it works as expected. This is odd, since it should only use `x-hasura-default-role` if no `x-hasura-role` is available, unless I'm reading this wrong:
https://hasura.io/docs/latest/graphql/core/auth/authentication/jwt/#the-spec

Anyways, for now I'm setting `x-hasura-default-role` and getting the desired behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're close to having the full picture here but are still missing some of the specifics.

Assuming you're not also passing the `x-hasura-admin-secret` header (you shouldn't except maybe for testing and profiling queries), Hasura **will** read the roles from the JWT if it can be verified correctly against the JWT secret that needs to be registered with Hasura.

The `x-hasura-default-role` that is signed in the token payload is the role that will be used to evaluate the GraphQL request as you've seen.

The point of the `x-hasura-role` header however, is that it can change the role that the request will be executed under **as long as the specified role is also inside the `x-hasura-allowed-roles` array that is inside your signed token**.

Image you had the following token:

```
{
  x-hasura-default-role: "member",
  x-hasura-allowed-role: ["member", "teammate"]
}
```

In this case, it would be possible to set the `x-hasura-role` header to `teammate` and then the request would be evaluated using a different set of permission rules.

This is not a security feature because once the user has been granted a token and if they're smart, they could make requests using either role. So you should only put roles in the `x-hasura-allowed-roles` array if you are completely comfortable with the user having access to that role.

However, this can be helpful in some application contexts where you want to evaluate a different set of permission rules based on where the users is in the app. Eg. if they're on the team page your application code can send the header on their behalf so access a simplified set of permissions that make sense for that context.